# Auto grab link from popup and add into input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I was wondering if anyone could help me.

I have made an fiddle so you guys can easly understand me.

I have an button and input form.

I would like somehow to grab that link from popup once page finish loading.  I've added google just for an example but it is an php file in real example.

So once page finish loading, an script would grab that link and paste it into input form.

I do not know if it is possible as nothing come up on my mind. Neither php, neither jQuery.

Anyone who knows if it's possible could give me some tips or example?

Comment: What is the URL to your jsFiddle?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H4CLv/

I dont know why I cannot add it into question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the popup window is on the same domain as the page that triggered it, you can use:

```
var popup = window.open(); // popup code
alert(popup.location.href);
```

On the other hand, if the popup is on a different domain, then you will not be able to access its properties due to cross-site scripting restrictions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Oh too bad... Well php script that is being triggered in popup is actually facebook.

Well thanks for explanation :) !